# Redirecting subdomains that doens't exist

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost

I have Apache2 running on domain **mysite.com**. I have following Apache virtualhosts:
mysite.com, admin.mysite.com, order.mysite.com, blog.mysite.com

**Virtualhost mysite.com**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias www.mysite.com 12.123.123.123 mysitehost.ip-12-123-123.eu
ServerAdmin help@mysite.com
SuexecUserGroup mysiteuser mysiteuser
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
DocumentRoot /var/www/root/www.mysite.com

<Directory "/var/www/root/www.mysite.com">
   Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
   FCGIWrapper /var/www/root/fcgi/php-fcgi-starter .php
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory>

LogLevel warn
ErrorLog /var/www/root/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/root/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Virtualhost **admin.mysite.com** (all others are similiar):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin help@mysite.com
ServerName admin.mysite.com
SuexecUserGroup mysiteuser mysiteuser
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
DocumentRoot /var/www/root/admin.mysite.com

<Directory "/var/www/root/admin.mysite.com">
   Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
   FCGIWrapper /var/www/root/fcgi/php-fcgi-starter .php
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory>

LogLevel warn
ErrorLog /var/www/root/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/root/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is that every other subdomains (that doesn't exist) will show the "/var/www/root/admin.mysite.com" content... For example if I type **blaablaa.mysite.com** to my browser, my admin.mysite.com will open.

Please tell me how to prevent that and how to set virtualdomain for subdomains that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone stumbles across this, and if OP never actually got an answer, even though this should be on serverfault, I'll write an answer. The way you do it is to have your **very last** virtual host in your apache configuration to be a wildcard. This is what I use in mine:

```
#Any subdomain that doesn't exist is caught by this
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tomg.xyz # replace with your website name. You can multiple of these virtual hosts for all of your domains on that server
    DocumentRoot /var/www/tomcatch # choose where the "404, this subdomain doesn't exist" files are
    ServerAlias *.tomg.xyz # Keeping the "*", change this to your domain
    Options FollowSymLinks
    <Directory  "/var/www/tomcatch">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simple is: set up a 3rd virtual host with `ServerName *.mysite.com`, and configure it to redirect to where you'd like it. Or, alternatively, you could of course not set a `*.mysite.com` DNS entry anywhere....